# Power amplifier large signal performanceand small signal performance

Tags: power-amplifier

I'am designing a PA 50W and the large signal performance is good (Gain, delivered power, P1dB, PAE, etc) but the small signal performance is bad espacially the output return loss < -8dB). Is this situation acceptable for a general PA design?
[image]

Comment: Yes, in general the large signal and small signal parameters differ.  S22=-8dB is not surprising.  It's not a problem unless for some reason you need small signal performance as well.